# How to change this VBA/XSLT-based code so the output is written in a single XML-File

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xslt

I got the following code as a result of a previous question.

The meaning of the code was to iterate through an excelsheet and automatically fill XML-tags with cell contents. The Output was a XML-File for every ROW in this excelsheet.

Now I have a very similar case and I know, that it can't be a lot to change to get it done. I want my code NOT to create a new XML-File for every row, but to fill everything in the same XML-File.

I want to automatically fill in the content of this excel-table:

[image: excelfile]

into an XML-Template that initially looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Codes>
<AreaCodes>
<Area>
<Name></Name>
<Desc/>
<Facility_Area></Facility_Area>
</Area>
</AreaCodes>
</Codes>
```

The column FACILITY has to be moved in the Facility_Area-Tag.

The column AREA has to be moved in the Name-Tag.

All the nested tags inside of Area should be repeated.

For my Excel-Example the output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Codes>
<AreaCodes>
<Area>
<Name>RA 001</Name>
<Desc/>
<Facility_Area>ZUF</Facility_Area>
</Area>
<Area>
<Name>RA 002</Name>
<Desc/>
<Facility_Area>ZUF</Facility_Area>
</Area>
<Area>
<Name>RA 003</Name>
<Desc/>
<Facility_Area>ZUF</Facility_Area>
</Area>
<Area>
<Name>RA 004</Name>
<Desc/>
<Facility_Area>ZUF</Facility_Area>
</Area>
...
</AreaCodes>
</Codes>
```

all in one file.

This is the XSLT-Template I have atm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="facility" />
    <xsl:param name="area" />


    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Templates -->


<xsl:template match="Codes/AreaCodes/Area/Name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$area"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Codes/AreaCodes/Area/Facility_Area">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$facility"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and last but not least the VBA-Code in which everything comes together:

```
    Sub Param_XSLT_Process()

...

        ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
       xmldoc.async = False
        xmldoc.Load "Path\To\Vorlage_AREA.xml"

        xslDoc.async = False
        xslDoc.setProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True
        xslDoc.Load "Path\To\XSL_SHEET.xsl"

        ' INITIALIZE NEEDED OBJECTS
       Set xslTemp.stylesheet = xslDoc
        Set xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor()

        xslProc.input = xmldoc

        ' ITERATE THROUGH EACH ROW, TRANSFORM, SAVE XML OUTPUT
       With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
           lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

           For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
               xslProc.addParameter "area", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)    ' ADD PARAMETER(S)
              xslProc.addParameter "facility", CStr(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value)

               xslProc.transform                                            ' TRANSFORM XML
               newDoc.LoadXML xslProc.output                                ' LOAD RESULT TREE
               newDoc.Save "Path\To\Output_" & lRow - 1 & ".xml"         ' SAVE OUTPUT TO FILE
          Next lRow
        End With
...
    End Sub
```

Right now, everything is dropped in a separate XML-File.

Could anyone tell me, what i have to change? I know that, for my VBA-Code, I should move those save-commands outside of the loop, but that doesn't work.

Sorry for struggling with English and thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a VBA class module `SheetWrapper`:

```
Private mySheet As Object

Sub Init(sheet)
    Set mySheet = sheet
End Sub

Public Property Get Cell(rowIndex, cellIndex)
    Cell = CStr(mySheet.Cells(rowIndex, cellIndex).Value)
End Property
```

Then it is possible to use

```
Sub Param_XSLT_Process()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument60

    Dim xslTemp As New MSXML2.XSLTemplate60

    Dim xslProc As MSXML2.IXSLProcessor

    Dim resultDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim worksheet As Object
    Set worksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim myWrapper As SheetWrapper
    Set myWrapper = New SheetWrapper

    myWrapper.Init worksheet


    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\SomePath\template.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.SetProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True
    xslDoc.Load "C:\SomePath\sheet.xsl"

    ' INITIALIZE NEEDED OBJECTS
    Set xslTemp.stylesheet = xslDoc
    Set xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor()

    xslProc.addObject myWrapper, "http://example.com/excel"

    xslProc.addParameter "first-row-index", 2, ""
    xslProc.addParameter "last-row-index", ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count, ""


    xslProc.input = xmlDoc

    xslProc.output = resultDoc

    xslProc.transform

    resultDoc.Save "C:\SomePath\transformation-result.xml"
End Sub
```

together with the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:excel="http://example.com/excel"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl excel">

    <xsl:param name="sheet"/>

    <xsl:param name="first-row-index"/>
    <xsl:param name="last-row-index"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="AreaCodes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="make-areas">
                <xsl:with-param name="area" select="Area"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$first-row-index"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="last" select="$last-row-index"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-areas">
        <xsl:param name="area"/>
        <xsl:param name="index"/>
        <xsl:param name="last"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$area">
            <xsl:with-param name="row-index" select="$index"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:if test="$index &lt; $last">
            <xsl:call-template name="make-areas">
                <xsl:with-param name="area" select="$area"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="last" select="$last"/>
            </xsl:call-template>            
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Area">
        <xsl:param name="row-index"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="row-index" select="$row-index"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Area/Name">
        <xsl:param name="row-index"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="excel:get-Cell($row-index, 1)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Area/Facility_Area">
        <xsl:param name="row-index"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="excel:get-Cell($row-index, 2)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I had hoped to be able to pass the Excel sheet object directly to XSLT to read out its cells but somehow MSXML didn't grok that.

Comment: I'll try it on monday and give a feedback on how it worked out for me. Thank you a lot!